# MySQL/PHP Sort with natural sort

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting, natural-sort

I writing a code to get mysql field values sorted.
my filed values are as below

```
**downloads**
N/A
10

50
30
unlimited
N/A
70
unlimited
```

those are on mysql table field.
i need to sort those assenting and descending like below

```
Assending
N/A

10
30
50
70
unlimited
unlimited


Desending
unlimited
unlimited
70
50
30
10

N/A
```

The space is some rows don't have data. i wrote mysql query like below

```
SELECT * FROM fltable  ORDER BY LENGTH(downloads), downloads DESC
```

But this not returns correct sort, can anyone help me with this using my sql or php solution.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM fltable  
ORDER BY case when downloads = 'N/A' then 1
              when downloads is null then 2
              when downloads = 'unlimited' then 4
              else 3
         end DESC, 
         downloads * 1 DESC
```

Comment: thanks i wrote a query, but it getting syntax error
SELECT * FROM fltable WHERE 1=1  
ORDER BY case when Offpeak = 'N/A' then 1
         case when Offpeak is null then 2
         case when Offpeak = 'unlimited' then 4
         else 3
END, Offpeak * 1 DESC  LIMIT 0,29

error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case when Offpeak is null then 2
         case when Offpeak = 'unlimited' then ' at line 3

can you help me thanks

Comment: I corrected that typo. You need only one `case` with multiple `when`s.

Comment: thank you it works without any errors when descending order the results is ok, but assending order sort it comes unlimited to first you can check that here row http://webxtreams.net/ccc/sorter/index.php when i click on offpeak we can see that

Comment: @SunethKalhara: You need to use the `DESC` keyword on **both** statements in the `order by`. See my update.

Comment: @juergend:  it is not workig in my console. may be mysql version issue

Answer (score 2):

For assending value use:

```
SELECT downloads, (CASE WHEN downloads = 'N/A' THEN 0 
                        WHEN downloads = '' THEN 1 
                        WHEN downloads='unlimited' THEN 4 
                        ELSE 3 END) as rank 
       FROM fltable 
       ORDER BY rank ASC;
```

For desending value use:

```
SELECT downloads, (CASE WHEN downloads = 'N/A' THEN 0 
                        WHEN downloads = '' THEN 1 
                        WHEN downloads='unlimited' THEN 4 
                        ELSE 3 END) as rank 
       FROM fltable 
       ORDER BY rank, downloads DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

- I know, this solution is very similar to another in SQL.

You can use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to implement any logic you need.

```
define('DV_NA', 1);
define('DV_EMPTY', 2);
define('DV_NUM', 3);
define('DV_UNLIMITED', 4);
define('DV_OTHER', 5);

function customDloadValue($n) {
  switch($n) {
  case "N/A": return DV_NA;
  case null: case "": return DV_EMPTY;
  case "unlimited": return DV_UNLIMITED;
  default: return is_numeric($n) ? DV_NUM : DV_OTHER;
  }
}

usort($strings, function ($a, $b) {
  $av = customDloadValue($a);
  $bv = customDloadValue($b);
  if ($av != DV_NUM or $bv != DV_NUM) return $av - $bv;
  return intval($a) - intval($b)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar way :

```
SELECT download, (download= 'N/A') boolNA, (download= '') boolBlank, 
       (download+0 > 0) boolNum, (download= '0') boolZero 
FROM table 
ORDER BY boolNA DESC, boolBlank DESC, boolZero DESC, boolNum DESC, 
         (download+0), download
```

That way, you can create groups to sort.

Which could result in something like :

```
N/A

10
30
50
70
unlimited
unlimited
```

Same result as above, different way. If you only have a few datatype (less than 3) that you need to group, might be easier.